# Atomic Update in Cloud Storage APIs?

Tags: atomic, cloud-storage

I am working on an app where I would like to allow users to bring their own cloud storage account. That is, the app needs to work with the APIs for as many cloud storage services as possible.

One feature that seems important is atomic update. The app reads a version of a file from the cloud, makes some changes, then uploads a new version. However, it needs to be able to detect if a concurrent update was made to that file (for example, if the user was concurrently logged in from a different computer). The ifGenerationMatch parameter in the Google Cloud Storage API seems to make this kind of thing possible.

Does anyone know how to accomplish it with other APIs?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to answer my own question, but I think after months of intermittent digging I found at least a partial answer in the form of a couple HTTP headers:

- If-Match
- ETag